# Run M2 from subdirectory

Tags: magento2, nginx

Magento 2.2.6

Have the main directory / and subdirectories like /germany, /france/, /poland etc.

each subdirectory has index.php file like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'us';
$params['GEO_REGION'] = 'germany';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

when I load `http://site.lo/germany` get normal result, but all static loads from:

```
http://site.lo/germany/media/image1.png
http://site.lo/germany/static/frontend/Theme/image12.png
```

etc

I also tried to add

```
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];
```

but have no success.

I use nginx server. Maybe I can there adjust something?

Can give some help or advise? Thanks!

Comment: Does each subdirectory have a separate Magento setup?

Comment: nope. each directory just has index.php

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: First, add that in the root directory index file and check it.